# Convert Seconds to datetime timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, time, seconds

In python how can I simply convert an integer of seconds into (h:m:s) using the datetime module?

i.e. 500000 ---> 138:53:20

Please, no tuple hackery.

Comment: Have you considered reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and writing some code?

Comment: So where is your code, and what exactly is the problem with it? What do you mean *"doesn't help"*? Also, what would you define as *"tuple hackery"*?